# How do you add a value to datepicker from an Angular Factory?

Tags: html, angularjs, input, controller, factory

i have an Angular Factory that gets a single date from the backend of my spring application, and i wanted to add it to an Input so the calendar input is always  set with the date obtained from the backend, without the possibility for the user to change it. How could i achieve this? Should i put it on my controller or directly on the button? This is my code:

Factory(concatenated with other .factory):

```
.factory('DataInizioGeneraCalendario', function ($resource) {
return $resource('rest/anagrafica/dataInizioGeneraCalendario', {
    get: {
        method: 'GET'
    }
});
```

Controller Function:

```
 $scope.generaCalendario = function () {
    $scope.modificaCalendarioDiv = true;
    $scope.successMessage = false;
    $("#idModificaCalendarioDiv").hide();
    $scope.element = new Calendario();
    autoScroll('generaCalendario');
    $("#idErrorTemplate").hide();
    $('#data').attr('disabled', false);
    $("#idGeneraCalendarioDiv").show();
};
```

Input :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" >
                    <label for="dataInizio" class="row col-xs-12 control-label" style="text-align: left">da Data</label>
                    <input class="datepicker form-control" placeholder="gg/mm/aaaa" required type="text" id="data" ng-disabled="true" />
                </div>
```

Edit : forgot to add, the controller function is called by the button that displays the input for the calendar.

Comment: Please check my answer below - it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your factory's GET request will return the date value asynchronously, it's better to have a `$scope.date` in your controller that will hold the date value that is returned from the server. Also, depending on the format in which you store dates on the backend, you might need to transform the value that is returned from the backend into the **string** format, so it would be properly consumed by the `<input type="date">` as per [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D).

In your code, you need to bind the input element to this value, like this: `<input ng-model="date">`. 
What it will do is bind this input to the data model, so that every time when user edits the input the `$scope.date` would be updated too.

**If you do not want users to be able to edit this date**, then you need to:

1. Keep the input field disabled `<input disabled>` (no need to use `ng-disabled` here, because you want to keep it always disabled). And also remove this line: `$('#data').attr('disabled', false);` in your function.
2. You the one-way binding, instead of two0way binding, like this: `<input disabled ng-value="date">`

Here is the working [**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/gorork/pen/jJXGox) that shows two inputs: one that is editable and another that is not.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but could you provide a coding example adapted to my code? I don't understand how to actually make it work. Right now my input displays Object [object].

Comment: @LordGriffith I could adapt it to your code, but I don't have your code. If you can create a minimal copy that reproduces your issue using Codepen, as I did for the Demo, I'd be happy to fix it. Otherwise, you can just follow my demo example. Your input displays `Object [object]`, because you're passing JS object into input's modal, while per Angular docs you should pass a string. You need to transform a date value that is coming in response from your server from Object to String. Also, make sure the date string is properly formatted as '2009-01-06'. Check the documentation link in my answer.

Comment: That's the only issue i have. Could you tell me a method that lets me convert my Date object into a string in JS?